Adding unmodified originals to new Photos library causes inexplicable error
Steps to reproduce:

Open existing Photos library
Export unmodified originals
Close and reopen Photos, holding the option key
Create a new library
Select all the unmodified originals and drag them into the new library

This should all be perfunctory, but when I do this the photos/videos start being added to the new Photos library and about 10% of the way in it errors with:

Some items cannot be added to your Photo library because they may be an unrecognisable file format or the file may not contain valid data.

This is on a 2023 MBP with plenty of free disk space and the latest macOS Sonoma 14.4.1 (23E224).

NB In case you're wondering why I'd export files from a library and create a new library from the exact same files, it's because I wanted to be 100% sure this would work before I back them up for safe keeping. Lucky I tested this, because indeed, it does not work.
Update
I tried for several hours to get this to work. I tried all permutations of export options (particularly around naming - e.g. sequential etc) and import options (e.g. drop and drag is one way, the File -> Import -> Import new / Import all). Every permutation failed; either erroring the same way as described above, or importing some tiny subset of the total photos1, or simply stopping what it was doing and not doing anything (I left my laptop for many minutes in case it was 'thinking' and checked Activity Monitor but there was extremely little activity).
FWIW: my solution
This solution loses location data and other photo/video metadata, but I will export all photos/videos out of Photos libraries and into more versatile formats (i.e. normal photo/video files that can be viewed without Photos app). I feel far less stressed just typing this solution, as Photos app has been extremely time consuming and has many dangerous bugs2.
1 Difficult to explain, but File -> Import -> (Import new | Import selected) both import subsets of all the implied photos/videos - extremely dangerous as this false-positive signals to the user that it imported the implied photos/videos when it did not; the user has to notice this (by either it taking suspiciously little time or noticing the number of files is wrong - too small); otherwise they may assume it worked and lose precious memories forever when they disregard the unmodified originals.
2 One example is when selecting items to import, command + a (select all) doesn't select all (!!) instead, selecting files in a pattern described by 'a few dozen consecutive files, then a few dozen missed, repeated for all the files'. Extremely dangerous as the user only sees a tiny fraction of their files and, if they're selected, could reasonably assume that 'Select all' selected all of them.
